# how to remove the default selectionof spinner?

Tags: android, android-widget

its me salman amjad
i m using two spinners in my app and hav  used if else structure on each selection......but when the app loaded the default selection condition executes....i want to remov the default selection can any1 of u plz help me in ths reguard????
also the frst condition not executes at frst....

```
 convertto.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v1,
                int index1, long arg3) {
            //from meters
            var1=Double.parseDouble(lvalue.getText().toString());
            var2=var1;
            if ((quantity[index1]=="Meter") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter") ))
            {
            Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            var2=var1;
            lresult.setText("" + var2);

        }
            else{
                if ((quantity[index1]=="Inches") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter")))
                {
                Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to inches",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                var2=var1 * 39.3700787;
                lresult.setText("" + var2);

            }
                else{
                    if ((quantity[index1]=="Feet") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter")))
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Feet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    var2=var1 * 3.281;
                    lresult.setText("" + var2);

                }
                    else{
                        if ((quantity[index1]=="Yards") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Meter")))
                        {

                        Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Yards",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        var2=var1 * 1.0936133 ;
                        lresult.setText("" + var2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //from inches
                if ((quantity[index1]=="Meter") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Inches")))
                {
                Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                var2=var1/39.3700787;
                lresult.setText("" + var2);

            }
                else{
                    if ((quantity[index1]=="Inches") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Inches")))
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to inches",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    var2=var1;
                    lresult.setText("" + var2);

                }
                    else{
                        if ((quantity[index1]=="Feet") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Inches")))
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Feet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        var2=var1/12;
                        lresult.setText("" + var2);

                    }
                        else{
                            if ((quantity[index1]=="Yards") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Inches")))
                            {

                            Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Yards",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            var2 = var1/36;
                            lresult.setText("" + var2);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //from feet
                    if ((quantity[index1]=="Meter") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Feet")))
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    var2=var1/3.281;
                    lresult.setText("" + var2);

                }
                    else{
                        if ((quantity[index1]=="Inches") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Feet")))
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to inches",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        var2=var1*12;
                        lresult.setText("" + var2);

                    }
                        else{
                            if ((quantity[index1]=="Feet") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Feet")))
                            {
                            Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Feet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            var2=var1;
                            lresult.setText("" + var2);

                        }
                            else{
                                if ((quantity[index1]=="Yards") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Feet")))
                                {

                                Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Yards",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                var2 = var1/3;
                                lresult.setText("" + var2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //from yards
                        if ((quantity[index1]=="Meter") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yards")))
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to meter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        var2=var1/1.0936133;
                        lresult.setText("" + var2);

                    }
                        else{
                            if ((quantity[index1]=="Inches") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yards")))
                            {
                            Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to inches",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            var2=var1*36;
                            lresult.setText("" + var2);

                        }
                            else{
                                if ((quantity[index1]=="Feet") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yards")))
                                {
                                Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Feet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                var2=var1*3;
                                lresult.setText("" + var2);

                            }
                                else{
                                    if ((quantity[index1]=="Yards") && (s1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yards")))
                                    {

                                    Toast.makeText(v1.getContext(), " to Yards",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    var2 = var1;
                                    lresult.setText("" + var2);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because when you execute your app for the first time and `onItemSelected` gets fired. To get rid of this situation you need to apply some logic stuff by your self so that when the Activity starts for the first time it doesn't fire your code inside `onItemSelected` and works when selection is made by the user.

You can do something like,

```
int spinner_counter = 1, spinnner_selected = 0; // declare globally

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v1,
                int index1, long arg3) {

           if(spinnner_selected < spinner_counter){
                  spinnner_selected++;
           }
           else{
                 //execute your code here
           }
        }
```

Comment: the default selection removed but still frst condition not occurs here...means for the frst time it is not calculating meter to meter conversion....??????????/